# Php: наложение watermark

Tags: php, watermark

Есть файл с watermark-ом, png, 500 на 100. Он динамически накладывается на большое изображение при его запросе. Реализацию скрипта взял [Отсюда](http://forum.php.su/topic.php?forum=30&topic=2146). Большое изображение до 1000 пикселей. При обработке изображения сервер 5 - 8 секунд думает, а потом отдаёт изображение, процентов 30% изображения сверху нормальное, а дальше всё серым цветом залито, [пример](http://threadbomb.us/com/gallery/1_05_12_07_7_01_36.jpg)? Я сначала подумал не хвататет оперативной памяти, было 32 мб, увеличил до 128, и вообще всё это дело для тестов перенес на vds. Как быть?

**UPD 2:
Я не спрашивал альтернативного решения по наложению водного знака, мне нужен был ответ почему, стандартная функция imagejpeg, с стандартным примером из официальной документации не может отдать изображение правильно, даже без наложения водного знака.
И ответа на этот вопрос никто не дал, а он есть и я получил на него ответ, правда совершенно в другом месте.**

UPD:
Решение проблемы:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
**imageinterlace($im);**
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
imagejpeg ($im, NULL, 60);
```

Comment: по поводу тормозов почитайте первый же комментарий с форума: 

> Накладывайте ватермарк при загрузке изображения. На лету пережимать пытаться - нагрузка жуткая.

Comment: Все превышения по процессору или памяти логируются, в данном случае их нет как на обычном шареде, так и на vds. В данном случае дело не в жуткой нагрузке. Ну и не может генерироваться картинка 700х700 пикслей так долго. Более того, я просмотрел кучу аналогичных решений в интернете у меня все работают с одной и той же ошибкой: долго генерится изображение и в итоге получается на 70% залитое серым. Пробовал на 3-х разных хостингах...

Comment: по поводу серого цвета -- может, у вас неправильно отдаётся размер? попробуйте сохранить картинку во временный каталог перед отдачей, и посмотрите, хорошая ли она. думаю. что картинка как раз в порядке, а вот отдаётся она не полностью.

Comment: может быть, проблема в том, что картинка начинает уходить клиенту _до того_, как полностью произойдёт сохранение? попробуйте всё же сохранить картинку в локальный файл на сервере.

Comment: С картинкой всё в порядке, локально она сохраняется правильно и очень быстро. Хорошо, как тогда показать пользователю картинку после её генерации?

Comment: хм. может быть тогда завести кэш сконвертированных картинок, проверять, есть ли картинка в кэше, если нету, на лету генерировать и добавлять (вы говорите, что это быстро), и отдавать клиенту картинку из кеша?

Comment: Ну проще всего тогда накладывать водный знак при добавлении изображения, + хранить оригинал. Но мне интересно почему не работает, этот способ, всё предельно просто - но возникают какие то грабли, даже в простейшем случае, код я приложил выше, отредактировав вопрос.

Comment: Как сказал @VlaD картинка начинает уходить клиенту на "ходу". Сохраняйте обработанную картинку в файл, создайте 2 папки original / watermark в одну оригинал, во вторую с водяным знаком картинку. И клиенту уже показывать из watermark папки. Принцип прост: загружает клиент картинку, она обрабатывается, сохраняется оригинал, создаётся картинка с водяным знаком, и на файл с водяным знаком генерируете линк, тут кстати есть тема как скачать файл, @KaZac показал как правильно через заголовки.

Comment: Ещё было бы круто реализовать свою систему Garbage Collection =) Если без регистрации можно будет накладывать вотермарки =) Это как доп. задание для Вас. =)

Comment: Я выше добавил кусок кода, в котором берется статичная картинка и просто выводится в бразузер (без наложения на неё водного знака) - при качестве более 60% картинка не полностью отдаётся, а с ошибкой описанной выше 30% нормальные, остальное серым цветом.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, заголовок отдаёт файл в поток, вам нужно: 1.Убрать заголовок. 2.Сохранить в файл картинку с водяным знаком. У вас неправильная реализация.

Comment: Я пробовал у себя накладывать таким способом- результат печальный: на 10 наложений в цикле ушло 5 секунды (localhost).  
Закройте сайт на обновление и наложите текст на все картинки.

Comment: @lampa, неистово плюсую- и рыбку сьесть и на карусели покататься.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ничего не закрывать, а на задачу выделить дополнительный процесс, который будет вызываться при каждом случае, когда картинка без ватемарка. При этом пользователю в первый раз отдается обычная картинка, а во второй раз - уже обработанная картинка. В таком раскладе никто ничего не заметит + картинки постепенно станут с вотемарком.